# sources of knowledge and interaction with other sysadmins

Tags: untagged

I'm new to the sysadmin world and I'm trying to get up to speed on all the facets of the job.  To avoid asking stupid questions at work I'm trying to use forums or q&a sites like serverfault.  besides serverfault, what other sites exist that I can lurk on to build my knowledgebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look into system specific forums.  For instance, if you're a Windows guy (or have to use Microsoft products) the technet forums are a great source of information.  There's never a bad time to start reading them, not to mention their archives are great sources for information.

If you're digging into Linux there are *MANY* forums for that, if you're an utter noob the Howtoforge is a good source of older information (and some newer stuff.) Not to mention specific distributions have their own forums and distribution lists  (Redhat support forums for redhat, Ubuntu for ubuntu etc.)

If you're into networking Cisco, HP et al have their own support forums.

If you're looking for professional advice on your career I'd look towards Linkedin communities/groups since that's what the site is for.

Or if you're up for the simple answer: hangout here, there are more questions asked and answered here than on most of those sites (leaving Technet out) combined.

**Technet Forums**
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/categories/

**HowtoForge**
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/

**Ubuntu Forums**
http://ubuntuforums.org/

**Redhat Forums**
https://access.redhat.com/kb/en/

**Cisco Support Community**
https://supportforums.cisco.com/index.jspa

**J-net (Juniper) Support Community**
http://forums.juniper.net/